# Get word being typed in WPF RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating my own IDE using WPF and I want to add an autocomplete feature, to do so I need to get the current word thats being typed in the RichTextBox.

I created this function that gets the previous word by moving backwards from the caret until it hits a whitespace.

```
private string GetWordAtCaret(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    TextPointer caretPosition = richTextBox.CaretPosition;
    TextPointer startOfWord = caretPosition;

    // Move the start pointer to the beginning of the word
    while (startOfWord != null && startOfWord.GetPositionAtOffset(-1, LogicalDirection.Backward) != null)
    {
        char previousChar = startOfWord.GetPositionAtOffset(-1, LogicalDirection.Backward).GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward).FirstOrDefault();
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(previousChar) || previousChar == ' ')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            startOfWord = startOfWord.GetPositionAtOffset(-1, LogicalDirection.Backward);
        }
    }

    TextRange wordRange = new TextRange(startOfWord, caretPosition);

    return wordRange.Text.Trim();
}
```

but for some reason it just retrieves all the text within the RichTextBox, does anyone have a solution.

If it makes any difference, here is the code I use for my syntax highlighting:

```
private void MainTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RichTextBox textBox = (RichTextBox)sender;
    textBox.TextChanged -= MainTextBox_TextChanged;

    TextPointer start = textBox.Document.ContentStart;
    while (start != null && start.CompareTo(textBox.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
    {
        if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            string textRun = start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
            int wordStartIndex = 0;
            int wordEndIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < textRun.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace(textRun[i]) || i == textRun.Length - 1)
                {
                    wordEndIndex = i;
                    if (i == textRun.Length - 1 && !char.IsWhiteSpace(textRun[i]))
                    {
                        wordEndIndex = i + 1;
                    }

                    string word = textRun.Substring(wordStartIndex, wordEndIndex - wordStartIndex);

                    TextPointer wordStart = start.GetPositionAtOffset(wordStartIndex, LogicalDirection.Forward);
                    TextPointer wordEnd = start.GetPositionAtOffset(wordEndIndex, LogicalDirection.Forward);

                    TextRange wordRange = new TextRange(wordStart, wordEnd);

                    Blink.Syntax.KeywordTypes type = Blink.SyntaxHighlighting.GetSyntaxType(word);
                    Brush keywordBrush = Blink.SyntaxHighlighting.GetSyntaxBrush(type);
                    FontStyle fontStyle = Blink.SyntaxHighlighting.GetSyntaxFontStyle(type);

                    wordRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, keywordBrush);
                    wordRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontStyleProperty, fontStyle);

                    wordStartIndex = i + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }

    textBox.TextChanged += MainTextBox_TextChanged;
}
```

I found a post similar to this but it was using some spelling check thing and I couldnt get it to work in mine.

Comment: Yikes, why not use AvalonEdit instead?

Comment: @JimFoye I dislike using other libraries for projects, I want more customizability and also it takes the fun out of it. You could say the same to people using OpenGL instead of a Game Engine.

Comment: You would have to invest much much more work into it. The RichTextBox is *really* heavy and slow. The user will experience it especially when there is a lot of text and text styling like highlighting applied. I recommend to implement a custom editor control using the framework's low-level text rendering API. Such an editor is a big project on it's own. You would have to draw and manage the caret yourself and implement an indexing system to index the input for text manipulations and text search.

Comment: I have tried something similar before. Even when you index the document changes to minimize the parsing it's unacceptable slow. It's slow even without any document manipulations.

Comment: All you have is the caret position. Without indexing you would have to traverse the document element tree for every input. FlowDocument is not the right document representation.